# MySQL - Select greater than Or a specific value

Tags: mysql

This is a simple question but I'm getting stuck on it.  Basically I need to add in the following AND statements to a query:

```
AND  a.d_max > '0' AND  a.max > '0'
```

BUT I would also like to make it so the max is either greater than 0 or = u because if it's set to u it means unlimited.  So something like:

```
AND  a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = u AND  a.max > '0' OR a.max = u
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is u a field name or a constant? Note, that you may actually want to use `> 0`, not `> '0'` because `= 'u'` is also `> '0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is ok, but you're just missing some parentheses:

```
AND
  (a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = u) AND (a.max > '0' OR a.max = u)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prioritize the evaluation of expressions/conditions using paranthesis:

In you case, I think you need this :

```
AND  (a.d_max > '0' OR a.d_max = u) AND  (a.max > '0' OR a.max = u)
```